# Best way to get a header with % of viewport without using vh

Tags: html, css

Hello i need a header with 80% viewport height without using vh as it only have 80% browser support

I am using this, but i am not sure it is correct or it will cause cross browser compatibility issues because the 100% height on html and body.

HTML

```
<body>
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  <div>
    Content
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color:darkblue;
  height: 80%;
}

div {
  background-color:darkred;
}
```

Comment: I've made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/javasluud/fqw7myup/) which shows your solution working. But since it's a bit hacky, it may not work as expected in all browsers. If you're worried about browser compatibility I'd recommend using `vh` units and a polyfill for it or do it in Javascript.

Comment: Or using position:absolute... https://jsfiddle.net/yaob3gc6/

Comment: @Anfuca

How would you do that with this markup?

https://jsfiddle.net/by9mv8k7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quick reference to see if something is supported in various browsers, go to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=height). From what I can see from your example, the code you want to use is perfectly fine.

Code to illustrate:

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }

  header {
    height: 80%;
    background-color: red;
  }

  div {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<header></header>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 
However i think there is a better way because if you check popular sites nobody does give 100% height to body or html.